# iCanHaz.js - separating templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache, icanhaz.js

Using [ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) is really nice - it's dead simple to create, load and render templates from javascript objects. However, in a somewhat big javascript application, the `.html`-file that initiates my application and contains all the ICanHaz-templates has become really crowded with template-script tags.

So how should I separate my templates to make things clear again?  Are there an alternative to IcanHaz.js that applies better to larger projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most client side template engines have the same concept.
You could load the templates remotely using XHR but that will add a terrible overhead of the HTTP request.

A better alternative could be creating each one in its own file, and having a server side script merge then in to your HTML page.

Finally, the last option is to add them inline in your javascript rendering functions - this will work for very small templates.